# How do I build a Spring Boot jarfile that systemd can execute directly as a service?

Tags: java, service, spring-boot, systemd

How do I build a Spring Boot jarfile that [systemd](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) can directly execute as a service?

Following the example in [*Installation as a systemd service*](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#deployment-systemd-service), I created the following systemd service that **directly executes a Spring Boot jarfile**:

```
[Unit]
Description=CRS Self-certification Service
Documentation=
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Environment=LOADER_PATH='lib/,config/,/etc/opes/crs/selfcertification'
ExecStart=/opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/crs-selfcertification-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=crs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However, when starting this service, systemd complains that the jarfile is not executable:

```
Nov 29 10:57:59 ubuntu systemd[24109]: selfcertification.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/crs-selfcertification-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: Exec format error
Nov 29 10:57:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: selfcertification.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 29 10:57:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: selfcertification.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 29 10:57:59 ubuntu systemd[1]: selfcertification.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

The permissions of the jarfile are `755` (executable by all):

```
administrator@ubuntu:~$ ls -la /opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/crs-selfcertification-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
-rwxr-xr-x 1 crs selfcertification 35978778 Nov 22 17:16 /opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/crs-selfcertification-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What changes must I make to the following Gradle build script in order to build an executable jarfile for the systemd service?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'crs-selfcertification'
    version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.opessoftware.crs.selfcertification.Application"
    layout = "ZIP"
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4.1208.jre7'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-dbcp2', version: '2.1.1'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

}
```

Note that this service runs successfully if instead of trying to run the jarfile directly, systemd instead **launches it using the Java Virtual Machine (JVM) from a shell script**:

```
[Unit]
Description=CRS Self-certification Service
Documentation=
Requires=postgresql.service
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
Environment=LOADER_PATH='lib/,config/,/etc/opes/crs/selfcertification'
#ExecStart=/opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/crs-selfcertification-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
ExecStart=/opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/startCrsSelfCertification
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=crs

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Shell script `/opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/startCrsSelfCertification` invokes the jarfile using the JVM:

```
#!/bin/sh

java -Dloader.path='lib/,config/,/etc/opes/crs/selfcertification' -jar /opt/opes/crs/selfcertification/crs-selfcertification-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

What might be missing from the Spring Boot jarfile that prevents systemd from executing the jarfile directly?

Comment: Did you `chmod` the jar file so that it's executable?

Comment: Yes, the permissions of the jarfile are `755`.  I revised my question to include these details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should instruct Spring Boot to repackage your project into the **fully executable** form:

```java
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

and this feature is only available for Spring Boot 1.4.0+.

Refer to http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration for more information.

**From Spring Boot 2.X+**, use:

```
  bootJar {
      launchScript()
  }
```

Source: [Executable Spring Boot 2 jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774075/executable-spring-boot-2-jar)

Comment: For bonus points, how do I change set the JVM parameters of an executable JAR?  For example, how might I set the maximum heap size, `-Xmx2048m`?

Comment: Place `your-app.conf` next to `your-app.jar` with content `JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048M`, refer to [deployment script customization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/deployment.adoc#deployment-script-customization-conf-file) guide or [launch.script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script) for details.

Comment: see question http://stackoverflow.com/q/40893530/107158 for more points!

Comment: from spring 2.x onwards, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47774075/executable-spring-boot-2-jar