# How do I set the JVM properties of an executable Spring Boot jarfile?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm

As a follow-up question to [How do I build a Spring Boot jarfile that systemd can execute directly as a service?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40870317/107158), how do I set the JVM properties of an executable Spring Boot jarfile?  For example, how do I set the maximum heap size (i.e. `-Xmx2048m`)?

Comment: From a shell-script I guess.

Comment: Is that the only way?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072187/how-to-configure-heap-size-when-start-a-spring-boot-application-with-embedded-to?rq=1

Comment: @Saravana, that question doesn't apply because my application doesn't use embedded Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

Place `your-app.conf` next to `your-app.jar` with content

```
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx2048M
```

Refer to [deployment script customization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-docs/src/main/asciidoc/deployment.adoc#deployment-script-customization-conf-file) guide or [launch.script](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but a way how to work around.

I have never opted for an executable jar since I believe it's more flexible to set the parameters from *outside* at app startup.

This is how to set JVM system properties and application properties via command line:

```
java -Xmx2048m -jar application.jar --paramname="paramvalue"
```

You can then get the parameter `paramname` in a Spring Bean or Service like this:

```
@Value("${paramname}")
private String paramname;
```

You can read more about that topic here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

**Edit**

Take a look at this answer which seems to be what you're looking for:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856394/272180

Answer (score 0):

- According to [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17613621/107158), one can set JVM properties in environment
  variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.
- According to [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12577771/107158), environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` also sets the JVM properties.