# Executable Spring Boot 2 jar

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

I try to install my Spring Boot application.
As first step I try to create an executable jar as described here:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html

However if I extend my gradle script (I'm using gradle 4.4) with the lines:

```
springBoot {
    executable = true
}
```

Then the build fails with an error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\spring\app\build.gradle' line: 15

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'app'.
> Could not find method springBoot() for arguments [build_3mwux4us8m2jn9yfcogqkbm4y$_run_closure1@506b241f] on root project 'app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

My build script is the following:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.M6'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


group = 'com.test'
version = '0.0.3'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-release' }
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-envers:2.0.2.RELEASE')
    compile('nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect')
    compile("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4")
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've linked to the reference documentation for Spring Boot 1.x, but you're using Spring Boot 2.x where the Gradle plugin has been updated quite extensively. It now has its own, separate [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M6/gradle-plugin/reference/html).

In that reference documentation, it [describes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-launch-script) how to create a fully executable jar file that includes the prepended launch script:

> Spring Boot provides support for fully executable archives. An archive is made fully executable by prepending a shell script that knows how to launch the application. On Unix-like platforms, this launch script allows the archive to be run directly like any other executable or to be installed as a service.
>
> To use this feature, the inclusion of the launch script must be enabled:
>
> ```
> bootJar {
>     launchScript()
> }
> ```

Comment: The link to Spring Boot Gradle helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing following gradle tasks manually:

> - gradlew jar
> - gradlew bootRepackage

afterwards you should have your bundled fat Jar.
(Thats how i solved it)

Comment: @BaurMarius This solution applies only to Spring Boot 1.x as the bootRepackage task has been replaced by bootJar in the gradle plugin for Spring Boot 2.0. The [Spring Boot 2.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) explains this change